# Cifrado de Cesar usando matrices y chars, error en los numeros

Tags: c, encriptación

Aquí tengo el código, básicamente tengo que usar el cifrado de cesar en C usando matrices y chars solamente, esto es lo que tengo por ahora:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


main ()
{
    char alfabeto[26] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    int m=0;
    int c=0;
    //char letra;
    int cont=0;
    char k[]={};


    printf("Introduzca un primer numero 'a':\n");
    scanf(" %i", &a);
    printf("Introduzca un segundo numero 'b':\n");
    scanf(" %i", &b);

    printf("Introduzca una palabra clave entre 4 y 10 letras (cuando termine presione '.'):\n");    

    //Falta una validacion para la palabra.

        for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            scanf(" %c",&k[j]);
            cont=j; //cuenta la cantidad de elementos
            if (k[j]=='.')
            {
                j=10;
            }
        }

        for(int j=0;j<cont;j++)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<26;i++)
            {
                if (alfabeto[i]==k[j])
                {
                    m=i;
                    i=26;
                }
            }
                c = ( (a * m) + b );
                printf("%c es: %i \t",k[j],c);
        }
}
```

Usa la formula donde `c=(a*m+b)`.

- `m` siendo la posición de la letra original por ejemplo: A=0 entonces m=0.
- `a` y `b` siendo un numero por escoger por el usuario.

En mi caso use `a=1` y `b=3` y `CESAR` es la palabra clave.

Acorde con la formula el valor de `c` para cada letra debería ser:

El resultado debería ser:

C es: 5 E es: 7 S es: 21 A es: 3 R es: 20

Pero es este en mi caso:

[image: ResultadoErroneo]

Comment: English: the returned value from `main()` is always `int`, when using a OS.

Comment: English: regarding: `scanf(" %c",&k[j]);`  Suggest follow with statement: `k[j] = toupper( k[i];`

Comment: English: `char k[]={};`  2 problems: 1) `{}` does not initialize, suggest: `{'\0'}`   2) `k[]` should be: k[100[`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no le das dimensión la variable `k`, por ello las variables que declaras en los `for` acaban siendo "sobrescritas" cuando empiezas a agrear elementos en el arreglo, eso rompe toda la lógica que programaste pues las variables tienen cualquier valor y no el que esperabas.

Recuerda que en C la memoria la administras tu, por ello si te pasas del area de memoria asignada a una variable, estas pisando otra variable, en especial en variables de función ya que se alojan en el stack (o pila).

La solución es darle un tamaño a la variable, cambiando:

```
char k[]={};
```

por esto otro:

```
char k[14]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

También podrías asignarle memoria dinámicamente con la función malloc, pero no es necesario ya que se utiliza dentro de la función únicamente.

Mi Salida:

```
$ ./a
Introduzca un primer numero 'a':
1
Introduzca un segundo numero 'b':
3
Introduzca una palabra clave entre 4 y 10 letras (cuando termine presione '.'):
CESAR.
C es: 5         E es: 7         S es: 21        A es: 3         R es: 20
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! :D resolvio el problema

Comment: de nada! saludos colega